# PyInstaller Executable Returns Nothing?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

Running into an issue where when building a python executable using PyInstaller, the executable itself returns nothing.. zilch. nada. There wasn't any errors when building. Has anyone else had this issue before who may know of a solution? I've been through countless older StackOverflow, Reddit, etc pages on different issues and got nowhere.

Python - 3.11
PyInstaller - 6.2.0

Have tried manually via executing PyInstaller which had the same outcome however, in general my configuration is as follows:

pyinstaller.py:

```
import PyInstaller.__main__
from pathlib import Path
from PyInstaller.utils.hooks import collect_submodules

path_to_main = "src\securityinsightreporter\main.py"

def install():
    PyInstaller.__main__.run([
        path_to_main,
        '-nSecurityInsightReporter',
        '--clean',
        '--onefile',
        # other pyinstaller options... 
    ])
```

pyproject.toml:

```
build = "src.securityinsightreporter.pyinstaller:install"
```

build execution: `poetry run build`

Result = nothing. I've attempting to add the --path directing it to the virtual environment site-packages which also didn't result in anything.

Comment: I doubt this is your problem (you should get an error message about pyinstaller being unable to find your `main.py` if it were), but FYI, if you're going to use backslash literals, either specify a raw string or double them up. Otherwise you need to worry about when characters in your directory name have a special meaning (like `\t` meaning a tab, `\n` meaning a newline, etc).

Comment: What I'd more immediately suggest is to try to break down your example into smaller, simpler pieces. Can you make the problem happen without using a poetry entrypoint? Then do that. Can you make the problem happen without your main being in a different directory than your working location? Then do _that_. Keep simplifying until either the problem goes away and you can ask "why does _this step_ break my code?" or it _doesn't_ go away and you have a reproducer that's as simple as you can possibly make it.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I've tried both: removing poetry and calling pyinstaller directly on the main.py as well as pulling main.py from the same directory structure. Both times confirmed to execute the program perfectly fine as-is, but both also resulted in the exact same outcome with building the executable via pyinstaller.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Not that it made a difference but i did take your advice and doubled up the backslashes on path_to_main rather than using "".